# Angular controller not being called

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I am new to Angular.js and trying to get get routing working but in my app the second bellow route does not call the `listController` so I am not getting back data.

I have been through many working examples but cannot seem to work out why this is not working in my app? I get the template back `/Categories/SixGrid` but as mentioned the controller seem to not being called. **Is there something obvious I am not doing wrong? Or can anyone share their knowledge on why this may not be working?**

**Updated code:**

```
angular.module('App', ['App.Controller']).
    config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/', { templateUrl: '/Home/Splash' });
        $routeProvider.when('/Categories/List/:slug', { templateUrl: '/Categories/SixGrid', controller:'listController' });
    }]);

angular.module('App.Controller', [])
    .controller("listController", function ($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('../../api/cat/' + $routeParams.slug).success(function (data) {
                    $scope.products = data;
                });
});
```

Comment: You say you get the template back from `Categories/List` while your route specifies that the template is to be found at `Categories/SixGrid`. How come? Also, you have an extraneous comma in your second route. Plus, your `../../` path is a bit uncommon for API call, although that shouldn't cause an error.

Comment: Thanks Stewie, was a spelling error. `Categories/SixGrid` is the correct template that comes back. Also removed the comma. The Api route is not currently ideal but am still in the early stages of dev

Comment: can you show your template. Better put your code on jsfiddle. so people can play with it and find what's wrong more quickly :)

Comment: Can you describe your file structure? In which file is the above code written? In which file is the definition of this controller? Has this file been referenced in your HTML page? If they are two separate files, the file containing the controller should be referenced before the file containing the above code...

Comment: In chrome/firefox debugging, do you see the $get request create any traffic? What if you put a console.log in there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to wrap controller name in quotes:

```
$routeProvider.when('/Categories/List/:slug', {
    templateUrl: '/Categories/SixGrid',
    controller: 'listController'
});
```

Also good practice is to define controllers by this way (because global scope remains clean):

```
angular.module('App').controller("listController", function () {
    //controllerCode
});
```

Comment: Thanks @ardentum-c. Still no luck, I have updated the code above to what I have now. Could the issue be somewhere else?